# Method must override superclass method

Tags: android, commonsware

Tutorial#7. I get this error "The method OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu) of type EmPubLiteActivity must override or implement a supertype method". The code is entered exactly like the book. The project compliance level is set to 1.6 on both EmPubLite and ActionBarSherlock. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

Your imports probably. If you are using ActionBarSherlock, make sure you import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu, instead of the default one.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
```

Not:

```
import android.view.Menu;
```

The same applies when overriding onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item), your import must be:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: I have all the needed imports for ActionBarSherlock and none of the default.

Comment: And does your class extend from SherlockFragmentActivity?

Comment: Make sure you're targeting SDK version 14 >= in your manifest.

Comment: The tutorial says minSDK 9 and targetSDK 11. I have changed targetSDK to 14 but that didn't seem to help. I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe the tutorial was written before the latest updates of ActionBarSherlock. If you have recently downloaded this library, you should target the newest APIs.

Comment: I downloaded the library a couple of days ago. The manifest for ActionBarSherlock have targetSDK 15, so i have tried that on EmPubLite to. But the same error occurs.

Comment: @Sjubussen: The answer given here is correct. You will see this in the tutorial solution in the repository: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/EmPubLite/T7-ActionBar/src/com/commonsware/empublite/EmPubLiteActivity.java

Comment: @CommonsWare: My code looks excactly like that but it still gives me the error. I have never beleived that the samplecode was wrong. I have tried all suggestions from Chinaski without any luck. Because i'm very new at this i hoped that someone could help me.

Comment: @Sjubussen: "My code looks excactly like that but it still gives me the error" -- the only known causes for the error you cite is either the invalid import or the invalid superclass, as Chinaski suggested.

Comment: How can a newbie like me figure out that. Any suggestion on what chapter(s) of your book i should read thoroughly to find out of this.

Comment: @CommonsWare: The imports are correct. I use Ctrl+Shift+O to enter them in to the code and they are the same as in your tutorial. If i understand this correct, the superclass is SherlockFragmentActivity? How can that be invalid? Also i did get the same error on "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)" but that has disappeared. Can any of you guru's tell me how to debug this?

Comment: @Sjubussen: Import the ENTIRE T7 project from my GitHub repo (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite/T7-ActionBar). If it works, then there is a bug in your implementation. If it does not work, then there is a bug in your environment (e.g., you grabbed some old version of ActionBarSherlock somehow).

Comment: @CommonsWare: This is probably a stupid question. How do import T7 into Eclipse? Or do i download it and then import it? Thanks a lot for your patience and effort?

Comment: @Sjubussen: Download the linked-to project, then use File > Import in Eclipse to import it.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Please forgive my ignorance. Do i need a tool or something to download this project. I opened the link in a browser but couldn't find a way to download it. As you probably have realized i'm not very experienced at this. Maybe i should start fishing or something instead.:-)

Comment: @Sjubussen: "Do i need a tool or something to download this project." -- go to the project's home page (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) and click the ZIP button to download the entire repo.

Comment: @Commonsware: I download the repository and imported the project into Eclipse, but that gave me so much errors that i decided to start again. I have emptied the Eclipse for all my projects, and deleted them from workspace. Should i wait 4.0 of your book before i start with the tutorial again?

Comment: @Sjubussen: I doubt that will help. Make sure that you are on the latest tools.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have started the tutorial again and finished #6. I get error message about "Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies". I got this error the first time also, and my attemp to fix this is probably the cause of all my problems. I have found that the ActionBarSherlock\libs\android-support-v4.jar has the size 271754 bytes while the EmPubLite\libs\android-support-v4.jar has the size 337562 bytes. Is this the dependencies problem? Which android-support-v4.jar should i use? Lets hope this is the last chapter of this problems. But i've learned a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Sjubussen: "Which android-support-v4.jar should i use?" -- either is fine. For the Android Support package, choosing the larger JAR (which therefore is probably newer) is not a bad heuristic to follow.

Comment: @Commonsware: Case is closed. The cause of my initial problem was probably that the first time i "fixed" the Jar dependencies problem i copied android-support-v4.jar from ActionBarSherlock to EmPubLite. This time i did the opposite and it works very well. Thanks a lot for your patience and your effort. To NEXT EPISODE...